# Skipping files which are in use by other programs while deleting

Tags: python, python-3.x, delete-file

I am trying to delete the Temp directory in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\

```
import os
import shutil

temp = "C:/Users/Sahaj/AppData/Local/Temp"
shutil.rmtree(temp)
```

Result:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/Sahaj/AppData/Local/Temp\\0cbcad42-9906-4897-b995-4375c35f1c09.tmp'
```

I want to skip these files and delete which one is not used by another process.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
Thanks for the comment, I figured it out
I removed files one by one using os.walk() like this

```
temp = "C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Temp"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(temp, topdown=True):
        if len(files) != 0:
            for f in files:
                try:
                    os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: You can get all the filenames, then delete it one by one using try block.

Comment: You cant use `shutil.rmtree()` for this, for the same reason that the command `rmdir C:\Users\Sahaj\AppData\Local\Temp` typed at a Windows console prompt would fail. `shutil` stands for *sh*ell *util*ities and it provides wrappers around built-in OS functionality. So if the OS won't do it, `shutil` won't either. To do what you want you are going to have to use `os.walk()` to visit each file in turn, and attempt to delete each file individually, with a `try...except` around the call to `os.remove()` to trap the failure caused by the file being in use.